# Converting 2-3-4 to Red-Black Tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, red-black-tree, 2-3-4-tree

I am familiar with converting individual 2-node, 3-node, and 4-nodes straight to Red-Black trees. And this Stackoverflow link is a good explanation [2-3-4 to Red-Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955246/converting-a-2-3-4-tree-into-a-red-black-tree). However, I have a question about the example given in that link.
This is how the Stackoverflow question 2-3-4 to red-black was illustrated [2-3-4 to Red-Black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygNGk.png)

I highlighted the part that I am questioning. Why is it on this guide [4-node connected to 2-node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge14W.png) I found and others on the internet, they say when encountering a 4 node connected to a 2 or 3 node, you need to switch the colors around. But in the StackOverflow example that I highlighted red, they didn't. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you say that you *need* to switch the colors around. As you only provide that image, the only thing I see is that the node in the B-tree is split, and the corresponding RB transition is shown below it. If you only look at the left column of the image, it is in line with the SO post. Same if you only look at the right column.

Answer (score 0):

The following image does not imply that the colors of the red-back tree need to be swapped:

[image: 3]

It merely describes the process of splitting a B-tree node, which leads to an *alternative* B-tree for the *same* data.

Then it shows how that different shape of the B-tree leads to a different coloring in the corresponding red-black tree, and how that new coloring is *also* a valid alternative.

But the translation from B-tree to red-black tree follows the rules you referred to:

If we look at the left side of the image, we see at the bottom layer of the B-tree a 4-node. According to the rules, this translates to a black node (c) with two red children (b and d). The 2-node at the root translates to a black node (a).

If we look at the right side of the image, we see two 2-nodes at the bottom layer of the B-tree. These translate each to a back node (b and d). The root 3-node is translated to a back node (a) with a red node (c) as child.

This is exactly what is depicted at the bottom of the image. The point is that these two *variants* are valid red-black trees for the same data, but derived from different shapes of B-trees.

Such a transition from the left to the right version might be needed when *inserting* a node. For instance, if an "e" would be added, then it cannot be added as a child of the "d" node in the red-black tree without recoloring. By switching to the right-side version of the red-black tree, the node can be added as (red) child of node "d".

Comment: Ok got it I think that helps clear it up. Why would you need to randomly split a 4 node? I figured the only situation which forces that is if you were to insert into your 2-3-4 tree a value that went down to that 4 node, making it split to accommodate the new value.

Comment: Yes, see last paragraph.